# How to import a module in a Azure PowerShell Function?

Tags: function, azure, powershell, azure-storage

Im trying to query an azure table from a function ( using Get-AzTableRow ) . Works very well from my laptop but the module "aztable' is not present in the azure function, and therefore all i get is a red screen :(
Is there a way to install it ?

Thanks !
David

Comment: Using the site for the AzTable module: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.0.1 You can use Install-Module -Name AzTable -RequiredVersion 2.0.1. Could you please update your question with the specific error message you are getting?

Comment: i tried to add "install-module -name Aztable" in the function code but its failing "Nuget provider is required .... "

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need to install the AzTable module in the Azure Function yourself. When you run the command, it will install the corresponding module for you.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

The example of the AzTable module:

```
$location = "eastus"
$resourceGroup = "charlesTable11"
New-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location
$storageAccountName = "pshtablestorage1122"
$storageAccount = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
  -Name $storageAccountName `
  -Location $location `
  -SkuName Standard_LRS `
  -Kind Storage

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$tableName = "pshtesttable"
New-AzStorageTable –Name $tableName –Context $ctx
Get-AzStorageTable –Context $ctx | select Name
```

[image]

Comment: You are using the "Az.Storage" module for this. When trying to use the "Get-AzTableRow" , it fails bebause its par of the "AzTable" module, not installed in the function.

Comment: @David72 OK, we cannot install the AzTable module in the Azure Function. But you can try to use the Azure REST API to achieve it. Take a look at the [REST API operations for working with entities in the Table service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-entities).

Comment: Thanks Charles, I followed this link https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/02/05/loading-and-querying-data-in-azure-table-storage-using-powershell/ and its working fine !

Answer (score -1):

Azure PowerShell is installed or updated, you must install module AzTable, which has the commands for managing the entities. To install this module, run PowerShell as an administrator and use the Install-Module command. 
You may refer to the suggestion mentioned in this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell

Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/supported-languages

AzTable module:Supported languages in Azure Functions  powershellgallery.com/packages/AzTable/2.0.1

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: I tried to install the module aztable  from the function but its failing :Install-Module : NuGet provider is required to interact with NuGet-based repositories. Please ensure that '2.8.5.201' 
or newer version of NuGet provider is installed.