# Azure functions load aztable

Tags: azure-functions

I was trying to use required.psd file to load/import module aztable,but won't work. 
The only walk around I found is to copy all module to function directory and import.

Is it the only way? Preferred one?

Comment: We cannot install the `AzTable` module in the Azure Function. You could refer to this [link](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2019/02/05/loading-and-querying-data-in-azure-table-storage-using-powershell/) with similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868104/how-to-import-a-module-in-a-azure-powershell-function).

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management). You can add AzTable to the `requirements.psd1` file, like this:

```
@{
    AzTable = '2.*'
}
```

Please also make sure managed dependencies are enabled in the `host.json` file:

```
{
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```