# How to query Azure Table from an Azure Function using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table called `csvtable` that has about a million rows. I want to query this using an Azure Function and return one row.

What I have tried is using an input integration with the table, but AFAIK, this only gives me subset of data inside a `$inputTable` variable to filter on.

I've also tried turning on the `identity` and using `Get-AzStorageTable` cmdlets, but this results in a `HTTP 500`, I assume it has to do with that Managed Identities do not support Table Storage (yet?) [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18407)

The code runs fine locally:

```
$storageAccountName = 'storageAccountName '
$storageAccountkey = 'storageAccountkey'
$tableName = "MyTable"
$storageContext = (New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountkey).Context

$table = (Get-AzStorageTable -Table $tableName -Context $storageContext).CloudTable

Get-AzTableRow -Table $table -CustomFilter "(PartitionKey eq '0401' and EnterpriseNumber eq '0401.021.061')"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include any code that you have written.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the REST API route as suggested by one of the top [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868104/how-to-import-a-module-in-a-azure-powershell-function).

Using Managed Identity I couldn't even retrieve the Azure Table.

Using the `StorageAccount` and `SAS`-key combo, I could retrieve the Table, but when trying to fetch data using `Get-AzTableRow` it seems that the cmdlet was not installed in the Function.

*UPDATE*

I managed to get it working by adding the `AzTable` Module

To achieve this in the portal:

- Click on the root of your function app
- In the **Function App settings**, go to **Development Tools**
- Open the **Advanced Tools (Kudu)**
- Select **Debug Console**, **PowerShell** (top bar)
- cd to home\site\wwwroot
- add a `AzTable = '2.*'` keypair to the `.\requirements.psd1` (using Set-Content)

Comment: Do you have the AzTable module installed into your Function app, using `requirements.psd1` or any [other means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell#dependency-management)?

Comment: No, but when I did add it it worked, I updated it how to do it for future reference.